# (Unity C#) Texture2D scaling mystery

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, scaling, texture2d

Alright, I've seen there's a number of threads about scaling a Texture2D both on here and the Unity forums. That line of searching brought me to now being able to scale Texture2Ds by using this class: http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/TextureScale

Now, what I'm currently working on is applying decals directly to the targeted texture. That's working fine. BUT, depending on the texture size and how much it's being scaled over it's geometry, the decal appears at different sizes (without any scaling, see attached image). That's what lead me to even look into scaling a Texture2D.

The mystery is, I'm not sure what kind of math to throw at the scale function to make the decal appear the same size visually no matter which mesh and texture it's on.

[image: decal diff size based on mesh]

Any help is much appreciated : ]

Answer (score 0):

If the texture is twice as large, the decal will be twice as large.  So, scale the decal by half, and it will be normal size.

In general, every place you multiply the scale for the texture, divide the scale for the decal by the same amount.

Comment: That seems to either cause an infinite loop or otherwise freezes unity: http://paste.ofcode.org/37Vj52eREqFAiLtfKDQTpAG

Comment: `DecalTex.width*(_targetTex.width/DecalTex.width)` is equivalent to just `_targetTex.width`.  As for why it's freezing: I have no idea.  It sounds like a bug with the `TextureScale` code, which you'd have to step through.  But is there some reason that `transform.scale` does not work for you?

Comment: I did try using the transform.localScale of the GameObject holding the respective geometry...that was a day or two ago and I forget what I tried. Whatever I tried, it didn't work and I moved on. Either I did it wrong or it wasn't the answer. But yeah I see the fail in my math above, been a long day lol.

Comment: I kind of dropped this for a couple days to take care of other tasks, but now I've come back. After some research, on the particular model I'm testing with, all the textures are 1024x1024, the reason for the different visual sizes is because of how things are UV'd by the artist. So that being said, I'm still stumped but in a different way.

Comment: I just sat down with an artist and it seems this very little to do with simply scaling the decal and a lot to do with some uv magic.

Right now I'm literally just stamping the texture.

What I need to do is determine which triangles belong to each part of the texture so I can limit the decal to applicable parts of the sheet. I then also need to do some other checking in world space so a decal can span two parts of the texture on different regions of the sheet when on the model they're actually attached to eachother.

So I don't think my original question is valid anymore.

Comment: Howerver, at least there's no more "mystery" as to what is happening.